# Print an int array and another int array that returns the remainder of the division of first array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I am extremely new in Java and having a problem with printing two separate arrays. I defined an int array of length 3 and a second array of the same length which is filled by remainder of the division of first array by number 19. First array store randomly generated values. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Hashing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[3];

        Random generator = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = generator.nextInt(80);

            int[] newarray = new int[3];

            for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++) {
                newarray[j] = array[i] % 19;

                System.out.println("array= " + array[i]);

                System.out.println("residuals=" + array[j]);
                System.out.println("\n");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

something is wrong with this code. what i want is this;

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[2]
```

and then

```
residuals[0]
residuals[1]
residuals[2]
```

but the result is this:

```
array[0]
residuals[0]
array[1]
residuals[1]
array[2]
residuals[2]
```

how should I correct this? I tried to correct the print by making the following modification

```
   import java.util.Random;

    public class Hashing {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] array = new int[2];
            Random generator = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = generator.nextInt(80);

                    System.out.println("array= " + array[i]);
                    System.out.println("\n");

                }

                int[] newarray = new int[2];enter code here

                for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++) {


               newarray[j] = array[i] % 19;

                    System.out.println("residuals=" + array[j]);
                    System.out.println("\n");

            }
        }
    }
```

but this time i get an error in this part:

```
newarray[j] = array[i] % 19;
```

it says it cannot be resolved to a variable. yet, it is already defined in the above for loop :( Could someone please give me a hand? Thanks

Comment: print them in a separate loop

Comment: division value should be 19. Not 13. Array length should 3 not 5 according to example

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: corrected the values! thanks for warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Hashing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[3];
        Random generator = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = generator.nextInt(80);

                System.out.println("array= " + array[i]);

       }
            System.out.print("\n");
            int[] newarray = new int[3];

            for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++) {


           newarray[j] = array[j] % 19;

           System.out.println("residuals=" + newarray[j]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. this one is what im looking for :( i am so dummy  :(

Comment: btw i changed System.out.println("array= " + array[i]); to System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); to print them in a single line but this time the result is like this:

[72, 0, 0]
[72, 19, 0]
[72, 19, 34]

why does it print the whole steps? how should i print the final result only?

Comment: [Pls remove duplicate comments]. Above System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)) is in for loop. So it is printing 3 times. Pls add System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)) out side the for loop. I mean after the for loop. Then remove above for loop exists System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); statement. If you did not get my point let me know.

Comment: Add System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)) statement  before System.out.print("\n"); statement

Comment: it really worked!! Thank you so much Chandana, you helped me solve all of my questions. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Print one array, then the other

```
for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++) {
    newarray[j] = array[i] % 19;
    System.out.println("array= " + array[i]);
    System.out.println("\n");
}

for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++) {
    System.out.println("residuals=" + array[j]);
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Hashing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[3];

        Random generator = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = generator.nextInt(80);

            int[] newarray = new int[3];

            newarray[i] = array[i] % 19;
            for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("array= " + array[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("");

            for (int j = 0; j < newarray.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("residuals=" + array[j]);

            }
            System.out.println("");

        }
    }
}
```

I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: so remove the for loop of the i index